Can I use htmlhint as a linter with 'mfussenegger/nvim-lint'?
I have tried to set this up (I am using Lazy as my package manager).
I added this to the relevant section in my lint.lua file:
  lint.linters_by_ft = {
    html = { 'htmlhint' },
  }

This doesn't get the diagnostics coming through. I have fallen back to using Ale, but I would rather not have to use 2 tools to achieve this. I've read on some other posts that is to do with how htmlhint exports the diagnostics, but I am not experienced enough to work out how to set it up.

Did you find a solution? I have the same problem with the same setup. Other linters I use and add the same way are working like a charm.
